# Why does my statement `\bool_if:nTF ....` not compile

Tags: expl3

In attempting to pose a more substantial question, I now find that my `\bool_if:nTF {\int_compare_p:nNn {...} = {...}}` statements won't compile. Why? Using `mandatory m-type` arguments in place of `optional O-type` makes no difference. I am using such statements routinely in other contexts, never any problems. Even throwing my standard large collection of `usepackage{}s` at it makes no difference. What the hell is going on?

```
\documentclass{article}
% RN. Melbourne Cup Day 2017
% BRIEF DESCRIPTION:
%  Why does this produce compile ERROR "undefined control sequence \bool" ?????
%=======================
\usepackage[check-declarations]{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}
%-----------------------
\ExplSyntaxOn
\bool_new:N \l_rn_First_bool  %  TRUE:= First=11
\bool_new:N \l_rn_Second_bool  %  TRUE:= Second=99  
\ExplSyntaxOff
\NewDocumentCommand\myTestingTwoIntegerOperands{O{11}O{99}}
  {  %  
    First~Operand~=~#1\\
    Second~Operand~=~#2\\
    % Testing First operand:
    \bool_if:nTF {\int_compare_p:nNn {#1} = {11}}
      {\bool_set_true:N \l_rn_First_bool}
      {\bool_set_false:N \l_rn_First_bool}
    % Testing Second operand:
    \bool_if:nTF {\int_compare_p:nNn {#2} = {99}}
      {\bool_set_true:N \l_rn_Second_bool}
      {\bool_set_false:N \l_rn_Second_bool}
  }
\begin{document}
  \myTestingTwoIntegerOperands[123][987]
  \myTestingTwoIntegerOperands
\end{document}
```

Comment: you have `\ExplSyntaxOff`  then use expl3 syntax

Answer (score 4, accepted):

after `\ExplSyntaxOff` normal latex2e parsing is in force so

```
  \bool_if:nTF
```

does not refer to the expl3 command with name `bool_if:nTF` but is

```
  \bool _if:nTF
```

an undefined command `\bool` followed by a mis-placed math subscript `_` and then the characters `if:nTF` which would be typeset as text.

You need to move `\ExplSyntaxOff` after the definition.

Comment: My silly slip of the finger!